# Group cohomology: Why does the trivial Z coefficient produce nontrivial cohomology

Tags: group-cohomology, derived-functors

Let $G$ be a group and $M$ be a $G$-module. Then group cohomology $H^q(G,M)$ is defined as the right derived functor $\operatorname{Ext}^q_{\mathbb Z G}(\mathbb Z,M)$. Here $\mathbb Z$ is the trivial $G$-module.

Now if $M=\mathbb Z$ is the trivial $G$-module there is an injective resolution

$0\to \mathbb Z\to I_0\to I_1\to \cdots$

of $\mathbb Z$ as an abelian group. Now equip $I_q$ with the trivial $G$-action for every $q$. Then the homology of

$0\to I_0\to I_1\to \cdots$

is $H^q(G,\mathbb Z)=\begin{cases}
\mathbb Z & q=0\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

Now in Weibel's book homological algebra the coefficient $\mathbb Z$ appears in many examples. It does not produce trivial cohomology. What did I do wrong?

Comment: In general $I_q$ will not be injective as a $\mathbf Z[G]$-module.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: The word "trivial" is misleading. Trivial should refer to the trivial module, which is $\{0\}$. But for various reasons it is usual to call "trivial module" the 1-dimensional vector space endowed with a trivial action. This object is actually not that trivial from the angle of (co)homology.